# Angular 4 Radio input

Tags: angular

How to create radio input that users are able to select all or single in **Angular 4**??

O Select all

O id: 1
O id: 2
O id: 3

when select single radio on id 1

array[] will display [1]

when select all

array[] will display [1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make radio button to have select all , because radio buttons are mutually exclusive. when you select one other one will be disabled.

Use check boxes if you need more than one selected simultaneously.

Anyhow here is the demo you can see for the radio button selection.

**[`DEMO`](http://plnkr.co/edit/j8a7ULwiUD7DhxuU5CDs?p=preview)**

Comment: check this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wbzqmz?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helps me to solve my problem.